# How do I apply DNSBLs on MS Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spam

We are lately receiving more spam. I was told we should use DNSBLs in order to reduce number of spam mails effectively.

All I was able to find out was to add IP Block List Providers manually. This is sadly not a solution I can work with.

Every idea is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to find a solutions that automatically adds ALL DNSBLs to your Edge Transport server as there are different DNSBLs for different purposes. You first have to decide how aggressive you want to be in directly rejecting spam and choose DNSBLs used accordingly.

- Learn the difference between [SORBS Zones Available](http://www.sorbs.net/general/using.shtml).
- Spamhaus also has several different lists. Learn [Which DNSBL should I use?](https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#201)
- [SpamCop](https://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml) only has one. I find it rather aggressive. It's fast and automatic in listing and delisting.

When you have desided which lists you will use, you have to [Configure IP Block List Providers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351199(v=exchg.141).aspx) manually, but it shouldn't take long with [`Add-IPBlockListProvider`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124358(v=exchg.141).aspx) cmdlet. Example:

```
Add-IPBlockListProvider -Name "Spamhaus ZEN"   `
    -LookupDomain "zen.spamhaus.org"   `
    -AnyMatch $true -Enabled $true   `
    -RejectionResponse "IP address is listed by Spamhaus ZEN"

Add-IPBlockListProvider -Name "SORBS Open SMTP relay"   `
    -LookupDomain "smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net"   `
    -AnyMatch $true -Enabled $true   `
    -RejectionResponse "IP address is listed by SORBS as Open SMTP relay"
```

There is [an article](https://www.redwoodnetworks.net/doc/how-to-enable-spam-block-list-on-exchange-sever-2013/) which has commands for adding many DNSBL providers at once, but I wouldn't advice using it as it will be extremely aggressive i.e. it increases possibility for false positives.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems I misunderstood the whole concept. 
Very good explanation!

Comment: Personally, I like to use Spamcop's DNSBL for *transient* rejects (SMTP 4xx, as opposed to SMTP 5xx, rejects). That has, at least historically and for me, stopped a significant amount of spam, and if the source host is legitimate and gets listed by accident somehow, it will likely get de-listed fairly soon and the message will get through with only some delay (hours up to a day or two; IIRC Spamcop has a 48-hour DNSBL entry time-to-live).

Comment: @Blufftl It is your perogative, but I would advice against accepting an answer so soon. While accepting doesn't *prevent* others from answering, it does indicate to the community that you feel your question has been satisfactorily answered, reducing the incentive for others to answer. Consider waiting at least a day before accepting an answer, to allow for people in different time zones to chime in.

Comment: I like your idea of _transient_ `4xx` rejects as it will cause the sender's MTA to try again later. Sadly Exchange 2010 [IP Block List Providers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351199(v=exchg.141).aspx) doesn't seem to support anything but custom error messages, only altering the human readable portion of the error but leaving SMTP error code intact.

Comment: @EsaJokinen On the other hand, should a legitimate client receive an instant NDR, they would take measures about resolving this situation right away, instead of getting hung in mail queue then after several days receiving an NDR, when actually a certain part of their mail flow has been impaired for too long.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thank you for your help Michael! I will try my best to become a good member of this society!

Comment: While I agree with @Vesper in principle, that hinges on the ability of the person receiving the non-delivery notice to (a) recognize its significance *and* (b) effect meaningful change. Most people don't have the expertise to do anything meaningful with a NDN (so fail (a)), and in the particular case of Spamcop's DNSBL there are no meaningful appeal mechanisms against listings so (b) is not available; compare https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/298.html and https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/297.html.

Comment: True. While most of the SMTP error messages has clearly stated and human readable error messages telling why the message wasn't delivered, most of the human beings called _users_ seem to be illiterate.